# first steps to xcode - table view issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios6

i'm trying to code up a simple table view > detail app to start getting familiar with obj-c. i use a dictionary to popolate the table, than clicking on a cell i get to a blank detail view. this work (i say it proudly). things get worst when i try to send information to the detail view, here's the debug error i get:

**2012-07-12 14:32:41.906 StoryboardTutorial[79624:f803] -[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6eae8d0**

**2012-07-12 14:32:41.908 StoryboardTutorial[79624:f803]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6eae8d0'*

****First throw call stack:
(0x13ca022 0x155bcd6 0x13cbcbd 0x1330ed0 0x1330cb2 0x2d41 0xdba1e 0xdbd11 0xed8fd 0xedaef 0xeddbb 0xee85f 0xeee06 0xc8a852d 0xeea24 0x27bd 0xa55c5 0xa57fa 0x93a85d 0x139e936 0x139e3d7 0x1301790 0x1300d84 0x1300c9b 0x12b37d8 0x12b388a 0x14626 0x1c4d 0x1bb5 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)**

and here's some chunks of code:

**DetailViewController.h**

```
//  DetailViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController{
    NSString *city;
    NSString *state;
    IBOutlet UILabel *cityLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *stateLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *city,*state;
@property (retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cityLabel,*stateLabel;


@end
```

**DetailViewcontroller.m**

```
//  DetailViewController.m

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize city,state,cityLabel,stateLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    stateLabel.text = state;
    cityLabel.text = city;

}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    detail.city = [dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.state = [states objectForKey:detail.city];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}


- (void)setupArray{
    states = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [states setObject:@"Roma" forKey:@"Lazio"];
    [states setObject:@"Milano" forKey:@"Lombardia"];

    dataSource = [states allKeys];
}
```

Comment: i really dont understand what u are doing in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. And where is the cellForRowAtIndexPath... Use an Exception Break Point it will give u the exact point after which ur app crashes

Comment: I do not think that you understood the usage of cellForRowAtIndexPath. Depending on its implementation your use of it may be ok, but I doubt that. However, debug it step by step and find out in which line the error occurs. Some object which is supposed to have a text property (and therefore a setText method) turned into a UIView object. Which is kinda strange. Reason could be some inappropriate type cast or even some memory allocation error, wich coincidentally addresses a UIView where a (deallocated) UILable was expected. Enalbe Zombies to find out whether some memory alloc. error occurs.

Comment: Make user DetailViewController object is created using the Below code. 

DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIView` doesn't have a `setText` method. The `UIView` you're talking to needs to have a property `text` in order to have a method `setText`

The error is most likely in one of these lines

```
stateLabel.text = state;
cityLabel.text = city;
```

One of these must not be the type of object you think it is (aka a `UIView` instead of a `UILabel`). Unless you're calling `setText` somewhere else.

Try changing it to

```
if ([stateLabel isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) stateLabel.text = state;      
if ([cityLabel isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) cityLabel.text = city;
```

Comment: ok but i'm using `stateLabel.text = state;` with `IBOutlet UILabel *stateLabel`…

Comment: updated answer. Also are you sure that this is the only place you're saying `text` or `setText`?

Comment: no, i'm not calling `setText` anywhere else… how should i set the label text so? and why they're not `UILabel` as declared in the .h?

Comment: make sure ur outlets are connected to the control.

Comment: no crash with the `if` condition so that's the point… now, my two questions up here, how do i fix it?

Comment: I don't know how you set this up and if you have all the connections right. Try using the code I put above to see if your classes are correct. If they are, then you might be passing invalid `NSString` parameters. You can see what's in the strings with an `NSLog`

Comment: You must have connected something that isn't a `UILabel` to a `UILabel` outlet. Look at your IB and see what's connected to the different properties.